# Issue with Xcode 4.1 & iOS 5

Tags: xcode, ios5

So basically i have upgraded to iOS5 and xcode 4.2 but after a little playing around i found out you can't submit apps to the app store with it (even if the apps are set to 4.3 or lower)

So i reinstalled xcode 4.1 (xcode did some back up thing so i still have 4.2) and started work on application building and such like. Submitted application to app store / testing on device everything running fine.

But suddenly (well just now) xcode has said:

> The version of iOS does not match any of the versions
>   of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS
>   SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or
>   update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

So i can no longer test apps on my device, nor can downgrade my iPod says apple...
but what im sooo confused about is that it was all working a few hours ago.

Why can't i do it now?

Anyone know a fix?

Thank you.
Eli

Comment: Ask Apple (or in an Apple forum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has apparently told testers of iOS 5 that any devices updated to that beta cannot be downgraded back to iOS 4. They will only be able to further upgrade their device and eventually install the final iOS 5 release. From Apple:

> Devices updated to iOS 5 beta can not be restored to earlier versions
>   of iOS. Devices will be able to upgrade to future beta releases and
>   the final iOS 5 software.

However, I've also seen this post: http://www.jailbreakmovies.com/2011/06/08/how-to-downgrade-ios-5-back-to-ios-4-3-3-tutorial-video/ which claims to be able to restore iOS 4.3 to a device. I haven't tried it, but if you're feeling adventurous and/or desperate, you might give it a go.

Comment: I have just posted a question on the developer forum to find it out, as having iOS5 is quite useful. Though not that useful if i cant use my iPod to test...

Comment: Kinda fixed it my self, not sure exactly what i did. But i think it had something to do with opening xcode 4.2 then opening xcode 4.1 Its working now so no need to downgrade :D

Comment: @Eli.Stone: I ran into the same problem, could you show me how to reopen Xcode 4.1? I installed both version but it always show 4.2 :(!

Comment: @chan well i would suggest removing both xcodes and re-downloading/reinstalling xcode, to just have one. http://macdevelopertips.com/xcode/how-to-uninstall-xcode.html